# How to debug Business Process in WSO2 BPS

Tags: wso2

How to debug Business Process in WSO2 BPS : Want to see input output in activity information list for each activity.. I am not able to.... Please Help

Can I debug the process in Developer Studio? Here Debug Means can we run it activity by activity?

Comment: Does below answer works? If not let me know!

Answer (score 1):

First you have to setup debug configurations in your IDE which is can be learn using this [wso2 article](http://wso2.com/library/225/)

Then start the BPS server script with debug option as follows.

```
<bps_home>/bin/wso2server.sh -debug 5005
```

After you start the server you will get this message:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

Then start debugging from your IDE!

[image]

This is the debug configuration I used:

[image: edit configurations]